# Cygwin: Changes to target files not reflected in hard linked files

Tags: unix, cygwin, wamp, ln

I'm using WAMP to develop a small PHP application. I'm also using Cygwin + Oh-My-Zsh to manage my git repository that contains the .html and .php files for the application. My source files exist in a directory outside of the www directory, so I created a hard link via ln to the source files. This appears to work at first, but any changes I make in my working directory are not reflected in the linked files. How do I fix this? I haven't been able to find any information about this particular problem, so any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: FAT or NTFS filesystem? Mind you: hard links are a very poor deployment tool.

Comment: Is it still a hard link after you make a change? Can you check the inode number with `ls -li` before and after you make a change?

Comment: NTFS filesystem on Windows XP. The inode numbers are the same until I do a git reset and revert the file. That seems to be when the link and target become disconnected. Is there a better way to accomplish what I want?